# How can I select every single element with JS or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, element

I want to select every single element in a document and make them color red when I scroll to them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("scroll", animationDivs);

  function animationDivs(event) {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();

    var divs = $("*");
    $(divs).each(function() {
      var currLink = $(this);
      if (currLink.position().top <= scrollPos && currLink.position().top + currLink.height() > scrollPos) {
        currLink.style.color = "red";
      }
    });
  };
});
```

**I used this codes but didn't work.**

Comment: Why not? What happened?

Comment: _"I used this codes but didn't work."_ Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

using JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll('*')
        .forEach(el => el.style.color = 'red')
```

Try it in the console of your browser to see how it works and [here's](https://plainjs.com/javascript/selecting/) a brief overview of DOM selection with JS vs jQuery.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/488073/6837445) is a similar question with a variety of solutions.

Comment: Not only div elements, I want to select "every single" elements in the document.

Answer (score 0):

First add some common css class on each divs and add following jquery.

```
$('.class-name').each(function() {
   var currLink = $(this);
   if (currLink.position().top <= scrollPos && currLink.position().top + currLink.height() > scrollPos) {
   currLink.style.color = "red";
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using jq, you could simple get all element withing the html by "*"

```js
var items = $("*").css({background : "red"})

console.log(items)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>

<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`currLink` is a jQuery object in your code. So use a jQuery method on it.

That would be the [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method in your case.

And I suggest you use an `else` part to your condition so the elements does not turn red after the first single wheel spin... Since `<body>` is also collected in `$("*")`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("scroll", animationDivs);

  function animationDivs(event) {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();

    var divs = $("*");
    $(divs).each(function() {
      var currLink = $(this);
      if (currLink.position().top <= scrollPos && currLink.position().top + currLink.height() > scrollPos) {
        currLink.css({"color":"red"});
      }else{
        currLink.css({"color":"initial"});
      }
    });
  };
});
```

```css
.spacer{
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<span>Scroll me.</span>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div>div
  <p>paragraph</p>
  <a>anchor</a>
  <span>span</span>
</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

**By the way...** Using an `.each()` loop on the `$("*")` collection on every `scroll` event is the **worst** jQuery usage I suppose I will ever see. I can assure you that you'll scratch your head pretty soon with a real web page with real content.

Every elements, including `<br>` and `<script>` and `<link>` etc. are collected using `$("*")` that way... And are compared in the loop. You should only use it when absolutely necessary and within at least a container to lower the amount of collected elements.... Like `$(".some-class *")`.